# Multiple images are generated in WP-content in wordpress

Tags: uploads, media-library

when I upload the images in WordPress using the dashboard. upload media. But when I go into the wp-content>>media or using Cpanel that multiple images generated with the same name. Now my question

1. is when I delete these images it will any effect on my site or it will generate them again.
2. This issue affects my website speed?

[image: One image generated multiple copies, how to remove the other image and used only the uploaded images]

Comment: This is expected behaviour and normal for WordPress, it should not be a concern

Answer (score 0):

1. When you upload an image to WordPress, it generates three image sizes by default (thumbnail, medium, and large).
   Put simply, WordPress automatically resizes images to help you save bandwidth and prevent you from having to manually resize images. For example, the image size you would use for a thumbnail is much different than what you would use for an image slider on your home page. By generating multiple image sizes, WordPress makes it easier for you to select the most appropriate option for each use case.
   If you delete any of the images your site will not generate them again unless you upload same image using media uploader again.
2. It will not affect website loading speed or performance in any way. But it will take little more space on your hosting platform.

Comment: Now I want to add the optimized images on site then how to take backup of media? with that images or only I uploaded images

Comment: @PallaviPatil that is a new question, ask it as a new question